# Connect to mysql with php using xampp server

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

This is the registration form, I want its data to be stored in MySQL database

[image]

It prints else part always i.e. failed to submit

[image]

My Php file below: I made a simple registration form. I want its data to be stored in database I mentioned in $db variable. I already created database in phpmyadmin which I mentioned in the file. But I don't know why this code is not working.
Please tell me what line of code is wrong and how should I correct it.

```
<?php
 $host="localhost";
 $user="root";
 $pwd="";
 $db="mohita";

$conn=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pwd,$db) or die("unable to connect");
?>

<html>
   <head>
      <title>Try here</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <form method="post">
       <input type="text" name="yourname"/>
       <input type="email" name="mailid"/>       
       <input type="password" name="mypass"/>
       <input type="number" name="phn"/>
       <textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="address"/></textarea>
       <input type="submit" name="reg"/>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>

<?php
  if(isset($_POST['reg'])){
       $yourname=$_POST['yourname'];
       $mailid=$_POST['mailid'];
       $mypass=$_POST['mypass'];
       $phn=$_POST['phn'];
       $address=$_POST['address'];

     $query="insert into login(Name,Email,Pass,Mobile,Address) values('$yourname','$mailid','$mypass','$phn','$address')";

    $run=mysqli_query($conn,$query);

    if($run){
       echo "<h1>Data submitted successfully</h1>";
     }

    else{
       echo "<h1>Failed to submit data</h1>";
     }
}
?>
```

Comment: Seems to be <form method="post"> you have not mentioned action attribute. Action attribute help the form to send the values on desire location <form method="post" action="name of your .PHP file where you have to send values"> in your case leave this as blank. <form method="post" action="">

Comment: @navjotsingh: the default action is the current page. You don't need an empty action value.

Comment: You can't *"Connect php file to phpmyadmin"*. phpMyAdmin is a tool (like MySQL Workbench) used to manage MySQL databases.

Comment: Your query is vulnerable to [SQL Injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) consider using prepared statements

Comment: Any error message by the way?

Answer (score -2):

Try this and let me know if this works!

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Try here</title>
 </head>

 <body>
  <form method="post" action="">
   <input type="text" name="yourname"/>
   <input type="email" name="mailid"/>       
   <input type="password" name="mypass"/>
   <input type="number" name="phn"/>
   <textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="address"/></textarea>
   <input type="submit" name="reg"/>
  </form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['reg'])){
   $host="localhost";
    $user="root";
    $pwd="";
   $db="mohita";
   $yourname=$_POST['yourname'];
   $mailid=$_POST['mailid'];
   $mypass=$_POST['mypass'];
   $phn=$_POST['phn'];
   $address=$_POST['address'];

  $conn=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pwd,$db) or die("unable to connect");
 $query="insert into login(Name,Email,Pass,Mobile,Address) values('$yourname','$mailid','$mypass','$phn','$address')";

 $run=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
   if($run){
   echo "<h1>Data submitted successfully</h1>";
 }

else{
   echo "<h1>Failed to submit data</h1>";
 }
}
?>

  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: If it's still not works then there is problem in syntax in your SQL query.

Comment: So, you want to `echo` some HTML **after** closing the body tag?

Comment: The provided query is vulnerable to [SQL Injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Why are you connecting to your database **twice**

Comment: Yes we know it's is. I don't thing so this form is used for commercial purposes.

Comment: Sometime the values $conn make an issue with if(isset($_POST['reg'])) so it's better to create a connection under if(isset($_POST['reg']))

Comment: "$conn make an issue with `if(isset($_POST['reg']))`" lol, don't say things you don't know about.

Comment: @navjotsingh: I need enough context, another user already ask about any error output, I'm waiting for it now.

Comment: My code works....I spelled wrong my database Table name. Thank you all. :)